# DataGridView filled from a DataGridViewRowCollection

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm filling up a simple `DataGridView` (`griVerifiche`) with some values coming from my object vBuilder.

I can't figure out why the values are not displayed in the grid (if I debug I can see that the rows have a value)

```
   DataGridViewRowCollection tmpRowCollection = vBuilder.getDataGridFromExcel().Rows; 
     foreach(DataGridViewRow tmpRow in tmpRowCollection) {
         DataGridViewRow rowClone = (DataGridViewRow)tmpRow.Clone();
         griVerifiche.Rows.Add(rowClone);
         int intColIndex = 0;
        //Looping each column to fill the grid
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in tmpRow.Cells)
        {
            griVerifiche.Rows[griVerifiche.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[intColIndex].Value = cell.Value;
            intColIndex++;
        }
    }

    griVerifiche.Refresh();
```

Comment: Can you please post your ASPX markup.

Comment: it's c#... no aspx output, anyways the grid has no columns in the designer (columns are added dinamically)

Comment: Is this a web app or a windows app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not refer to the last Row of the Grid because there is always an extra (last) row in the grid, used for adding new data.
Instead refer to the one before that (count-2).